# Erro ao fazer insert - String or binary data > would be truncated

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Ao fazer esse insert:

```
INSERT INTO t_cmo_oit1980_leitura(id_oit_let,id_oit,rx_num, dt_rx)
SELECT (1),
  (SELECT id_oit
   FROM t_cmo_oit1980
   WHERE id_oit = 6574),
  (SELECT rx_num
   FROM t_cmo_planilha_leitura
   WHERE id_xfc = 39517),
  (SELECT dt_rx
   FROM t_cmo_planilha_leitura
   WHERE id_xfc = 39517);

GO
```

Acontece o erro:

> Mensagem 8152, Nível 16, Estado 14, Linha 19 String or binary data
>   would be truncated. The statement has been terminated.

Tabela `t_cmo_planilha_leitura(Origem)`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tabela `t_cmo_oit1980_leitura(Destino)`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Pode não ter relação com o campo do tipo data. A mensagem diz "String ou dados binários seriam truncados". Pode detalhar os tipos de dados de cada campo destino e fonte dessa consulta?

Comment: @Pagotti, vou editar o post e colocar a estrutura de cada tabela.

Comment: @Pagotti, você tem razão. Confundi Data com Date. Já sei qual é o erro. A tabela Origem vem de uma planilha excel e ao criar pelo DTS, ele monta os varchars com 255 e no campo destino é varchar(6) e isso para os demais campos. Vou recriar a tabela e carregar novamente. sendo só isso, mude seu comentário em resposta para eu marcá-lo.

Comment: @pnet editei a sua pergunta para torná-la mais abrangente. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O problema está na verdade, no campo **`RX_NUM`**.

Na tabela `t_cmo_planilha_leitura` ele é do tipo `varchar(255)`
E na tabela `t_cmo_oit1980_leitura` ele é do tipo `varchar(6)`

Ou seja, são de tamanhos diferentes e o erro é causado porque o **Destino** não tem espaço suficiente para armazenar o que vem da **Origem**.

**Sugestões de correção**

1.
 O melhor seria alterar para `varchar(255)`, no entando, você pode alterar para o tamanho máximo.

Verificar qual o espaço máximo utilizado na origem:

```
select max(len(rx_num)) from t_cmo_planilha_leitura
```

Sabendo o tamanho máximo, altere na tabela destino:

```
alter table t_cmo_planilha_leitura alter column rx_num varchar(o_valor_max)
```

2.
Ou você pode limitar diretamente o que será inserido na tabela de destino utilizando o comando [`left`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms177601.aspx):

```
insert into t_cmo_oit1980_leitura(id_oit_let,id_oit,rx_num, dt_rx)  
    select
    (1),
    (select id_oit from t_cmo_oit1980 where id_oit = 6574),
    (select left(rx_num,6) from t_cmo_planilha_leitura where id_xfc = 39517),
    (select dt_rx from t_cmo_planilha_leitura where id_xfc = 39517);
    go
```

Answer (score 2):

Você está tentando adicionar um valor maior que a coluna permite.

`RX_NUM` em `t_cmo_oit1980_leitura`(*tabela que recebe os dados*) tem um comprimento `varchar(6)`, e `RX_NUM` em `t_cmo_planilha_leitura` tem um comprimento `varchar(255)`.

Supomos que você tenha esse texto abaixo adicionado há `RX_NUM` em `t_cmo_planilha_leitura`:

> Microsoft SQL Server. Sistema de gerenciamento de banco de dados
>   relacional (SGBD). O Microsoft SQL Server é um SGBD - sistema
>   gerenciador de Banco de dados relacional desenvolvido pela Microsoft.
>   Foi criado em parceria com a Sybase em 1988 inicialmente para a
>   plataforma OS/2.

E tentar adicionar esse texto em `t_cmo_oit1980_leitura`, irá ocorrer o erro que você postou.